# Trying to call Toaster or Custom function inside setOnUtteranceProgressListener

Tags: android, listener, text-to-speech

In my main Fragment, I have implemented TextToSpeech `mainFragment extends Fragment implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener`.

The text to speech is working fine, also i have added an `UtteranceProgressListener` which is working.

My problem : 
Am unable to call any custom functions eg `gotoNextChapter()` or even a simple `Toaster`.
getting error `Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`

Any suggestions or solutions welcomed....

My code snippet:

```
UtteranceProgressListener SpeechListener = new UtteranceProgressListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStart(String utteranceId) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),utteranceId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDone(String utteranceId) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),utteranceId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                gotoNextChapter(); <====function I want to call
                read_mode = 0;
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String utteranceId) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),utteranceId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };
```

Setting the utterance complete listener:

```
myTTS.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(SpeechListener);
```

Error am getting:

```
Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
                                                            at
android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:209)
                                                            at
android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:123)
                                                            at
android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:350)
                                                            at
android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:106)
                                                            at
android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:264)
                                                            at com.MainActivity$Read$10.onDone(MainActivity.java:1252)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok I got a solution, now my question just seems trivial

my updated code looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onDone(String utteranceId) {

runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),utteranceId,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
gotoNextChapter(); <====function I want to call
read_mode = 0;
                }
            });
}
```

Thanks to these guyes here:
[How can I Toast after Text to Speech finish speaking Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35982041/how-can-i-toast-after-text-to-speech-finish-speaking-android?rq=1)
and [When may we need to use runOnUiThread in android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10135353/when-may-we-need-to-use-runonuithread-in-android-application)

Answer (score 1):

If you are in Activity:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() { 
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
    }
});
```

If you are in a fragment:

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();         
    }
});
```

Else you can do this:

```
Handler mainHandler = new Handler(context.getMainLooper());

Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override 
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
    } 
};
mainHandler.post(myRunnable);
```